# Can mutithreading be used to performance tune my app

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

In my application i open connection for about 70 servers each having 8 databases on average(the servers Are categorized into environments viz development, production, UaT, sit,training, misc,Qa ).
The application will check for existence of a user in the each database and fetch details if the user exists.
I have used a method to call the service this method will pass the user id as input inturn the service will check the user across the databases And fetch The details. 
this whole process is taking too much of time that the idle time in UI is around 5 - 10 mins.

How can we tune the performance of this application. I thought Of implementing multi-threading and fetching detains in environment basis. but I am not sure if we can call a method with Return type in the application and with input parameters.

Please suggest a way to improve performance.

```
public List<AccessDetails> GetAccessListOfMirror(string mirrorId,string server)
        {
            List<AccessDetails> accessOfMirror = new List<AccessDetails>();
            string loginUserId = SessionManager.Session.Current.LoggedInUserName;
            string userPassword = SessionManager.Session.Current.Password;
            using (Service1Client client = new Service1Client())
            {
                client.Open();
                    accessOfMirror = client.GetMirrorList(mirrorId, server, loginUserId, userPassword);
            }

            return accessOfMirror;
        }
```

Service method

```
public List<AccessDetails> GetMirrorList(string mirrorId, string server, string userId, string userPassword)
        {

            string mirrorUser = mirrorId.ToString();
            List<ConnectionStringContract> connectionStrings = new List<ConnectionStringContract>();
            try
            {
                connectionStrings = GetConnectionString(server);
            }
            catch (FaultException<ServiceData> exe)
            {
                throw exe;
            }

            AseConnection aseConnection = default(AseConnection);
            List<AccessRequest> mirrorUsers = new List<AccessRequest>();
            List<FacetsOnlineAccess> foaAccess = new List<FacetsOnlineAccess>();
            List<AccessDetails> accessDetails = new List<AccessDetails>();
            AccessDetails accDetails = new AccessDetails();                            
            AccessRequest access;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(server))
                connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Where(x => x.Server == server).ToList();
            foreach (ConnectionStringContract connection in connectionStrings)
            {
                string connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;

                AseCommand aseCommand = new AseCommand();
                using (aseConnection = new AseConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        aseConnection.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            List<Parameter> parameter = new List<Parameter>();
                            Parameter param;
                            param = new Parameter();
                            param.Name = "@name_in_db";
                            param.Value = mirrorUser.ToLower().Trim();
                            parameter.Add(param);
                            int returnCode = 0;
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            try
                            {
                                ds = DataAccess.ExecuteStoredProcedure(connectionString, Constant.SP_HELPUSER, parameter, out returnCode);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                            if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                                {
                                    access = new AccessRequest();
                                    if (row.ItemArray[0].ToString() == mirrorUser)
                                        access.Group = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                                    else
                                        access.Group = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                                    access.Environment = connection.Environment.Trim();
                                    access.Server = connection.Server.Trim();
                                    access.Database = connection.Database.Trim();
                                    mirrorUsers.Add(access);
                                }                               

                            }


                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ConEx)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            accDetails.AccessList = mirrorUsers;
            //accDetails.FOAList = foaAccess;
            accessDetails.Add(accDetails);
            return accessDetails;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops can sometimes reduce speeds, especially loops inside loops. I/O operations are always pretty slow. You have a loop with i?o. So if you would execute this I/O operations on parallel threads, the performance would increase.

You could translate

```
foreach (ConnectionStringContract connection in connectionStrings)
{
    ...
}
```

into:

```
Parallel.ForEach(connectionStrings, connectionString =>
{
    ...
}
```

Inside you should lock the commonly used variables, like `mirrorUsers` with a lock.
I think this is a great start. Meanwhile I will look for other performance issues.

Comment: Great start indeed. Also, if the commonly used variables are very frequently used but fast to copy, you could copy them in the lambda expression and it might enhance performance as well. In general, though, the first thing you wanna do it run an actual performance test. Make sure that the thing that slows you down is what you think it is.

Comment: @Yorye: I do not understand how, in this case, lamda will increase speed. Can you give us an example to clearify? And yes, measuring is also very important!

Comment: I meant that locking the variables might slow things down if they are used a lot, since only one or two threads will be actually running smoothly in a given moment. To maximize the efficiency of the parallelism, you will want to avoid any dependency between the threads, so you could copy the variables within the lambda and use them freely. This is a general tip, though. In this case, you'd obviously want the lists shared between the paralleled threads. What you COULD do, however, is have a local list for each thread, and lock the outter-scoped list only once in the end, to use `AddRange`.

Comment: True, if you can prevent locking, prevent it. In my opinion locking consumes microseconds, will I/O delays (hondreds of) milliseconds. I have the feeling in this case it will not be a problem. But you are right in your first remark: we just have to measure it. I still do not understand your "lambda" solution. Perhapse my lack of knowledge of lambda's.

Comment: When I say lambda, I'm referring to this: `connectionString => { ... }` as a block of code. So when I say copy variables in lambda, I mean `connectionString => { var lstCpy = Copy(someImportantList); ... WorkWithList(lstCpy); }`

Comment: @Yorye: Now I can follow you. I had the impression you wanted to create another lambda, and do something in there. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to take advantage of multi threading without too much hassle...

You should probably make use of the threadpool, so you don't spawn too many threads all running at the same time. You can read about the built in threadpool here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

What you should do is to extract the body of your `foreach` loop to a static method. Any parameters should be made into a model that can be passed to the thread. Because then you can use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(object)` to start the threads.

Regarding multiple threads writing to the same resource (list or whatever) you can use any kind of mutex, lock or threadsafe component. Using locks is quite simple:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Assuming .NET 4.0 can be used, it's much easier to use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) instead of using ThreadPool.

Comment: -1: please don't post .NET 2.0 links unless the answer is specific to .NET 2.0.